# Connect to proxy with connection timeout

Tags: java, apache, http, proxy

I am trying to connect to a proxy with a piece of code but I want a timeout to the connection request that I perform to the proxy. 
This code previously shared on the site 
[How to check if proxy is working in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030908/how-to-check-if-proxy-is-working-in-java)
sets a timeout to the request to the website and not to the request for the proxy. As a result it can lead to extended waiting time if the proxy is password protected or for any other reason.

Can someone explain to me if it is possible to set a timeout for the connection to the proxy or any ways that I can confirm the proxy with a timeout and without pinging the proxy?

Comment: The connection to the website is done via the connection to the proxy. They aren't two different things. A timeout isn't going to fix an authorization issue. Your question remains unclear.